# Div keeps overlapping upper div

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, components

i'm ussing Angular4 and i'm creating visual components.

I created 2 elements, one is is inline-block, and the second one is block. By logict, if i put the inline-block first, it should have the right space free and the second component shoud appear on the next line.

Well in my case, when i put the block one first, the inline-bloc goes down, but when i put the inline block first, the second one keeps going up and overlaps (and mix the elements)...

This is how it looks in the first case

[image]

And this is what happens when i put the element block second

[image]

They both have its sizes defined and its displays... Can you help me?

Comment: why not just two `display:block` ?

Comment: Becouse as i mark in the picture, they can be several inline blocks elements. I need only the large one to be block.

Comment: Forget about old inline-block stuff anyway. Flexbox is life, Flexbox is our savior. Anyway, it would be easier if we had your HTML + CSS to work with.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [MCVE]

Comment: I stablish the desire behavior ( keep everything where it should and not mix the things ), also stablish the problem... Said that the divs are block and inline block. Its all it needs. I also included images, so i don't see the problem @Pete

Comment: Where's the code, do you just expect to guess what your problem is? Or do you expect us to magic a solution out of thin air?  How do you expect anyone to do anything if they don't see your current code and css?  Anyway if you had actually read my previous comment properly you would see exactly what is wrong.  There's even a link for you to click on and read, but hey that's asking you to put some effort in so I guess you didn't bother doing that either

Comment: without the code we can't help you :/

Comment: I agree, add some code. It will be really simple to solve once we see the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is not a problem with the display property as it is not the usual behaviour of the `block` and `inline-block` values. Putting one or another after or before doesn't should affect to show each one in a different row.

Check this snippet:

```css
.container{

border: 1px solid black;
margin: 1em;
padding: 1em;

}
.blocky{ 
  display: block; 
  height: 2em; border: 1px solid red; 
 }
.inliny-blocky{
      display: inline-block; height: 1em; 
      width: 2em; border: 1px solid green; 
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inliny-blocky"></div>
  <div class="blocky">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="blocky"></div>
  <div class="inliny-blocky"></div>
</div>
```

Check any other css style that makes the divs overlap.

Answer (score 0):

use the parent div with the inline-block

Answer (score -1):

Use

tag as per below

```
<p>
  <md-checkbox class="example-margin" ngDefaultControl></md-checkbox>
</p>
<p>
    <md-input-container>
      <input mdInput placeholder="Name" formControlName="name" 
         maxlength="300" ngDefaultControl>
    </md-input-container>
</p>
```